# Add Div below the Input Type text

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part, hide-elements

I want to show and add the existing `Div` right below the input type text box on Button click event. I'm using `content editor web part` to show the below `html`

```
<div id="Div1" style="Display:None;">MyDiv</div>
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="button" id="Click">
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Or just pure javascript?

Comment: Using Jquery, But i cant get it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/vzmnJ/

Comment: Thanks. But I want to show the Div after the text box without altering the above HTML. (i.e)  I want to show the Div from Content editor web part after the text box in the newform.aspx

Comment: You can not if you stick to *without altering the above HTML*, unless you add same hairy CSS script to make room after text1 and move Div1 to another (absolute) location on screen

Comment: do you have any parent tag that encloses all the above mentioned tag?